# preg_replace to strip leading slash

Tags: php, regex

I would like to strip the leading slash and the querystring from a URL but can't work out how to do them both. I have this code which works perfectly for stripping the querystring, but it leaves the leading slash

```
preg_replace('/\?.*$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

If my URL is `www.mysite.com/myPage?querystring=123`, the above leaves me with `/myPage`. How can I tweak this so I can remove the leading slash too?

Also, can you point me at a resource to help me understand `preg_replace` pattern matching please?

Comment: Why not simply use http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php and then string functions like http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I might favor PHP's simple string functions over regex in such a simple case:

```
$addr  = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'); // zap a leading slash
$q_pos = strpos($addr, '?'); // get the string position of a '?'
$addr  = $q_pos !== FALSE ? substr($addr, 0, $q_pos) : $addr; // pull out URI
```

PHP's [`strpos()`<sup>*docs*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns an integer value, so it's possible that `$q_pos === 0` ... this is why we check `$q_pos !== FALSE`.

**UPDATE**

I suppose I should answer the question, though ... so to actually use a regex in this situation ...

```
$address = '/test/url/test.php?extra';
$pattern = '{^/?([^\?]+)\?.*$}';
$replace = '$1';
$address = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $address);
echo "$address"; // outputs: test/url/test.php
```

How does this work? Well ... our pattern specifies a capture group `([^\?]+)` using the parentheses that grabs everything after an *optional* forward slash `/?` up to the first occurrence of an *optional* `\?` in the string. Note that we escape the actual question mark character with a backslash because it has meaning in the context of regex patterns. The final part of the regex pattern `.*` simply matches zero or more characters out to the end of the string.

Finally, our replacement simply specifies the `$1` to reference the text we captured with our original parentheses grouping `([^\?]+)`.

One other thing to note that regex novices often fail to realize is that you aren't **required** to use `/` as pattern delimiters. In a case like this where we're matching actual forward slash characters I use something else (like the curly braces).

I usually point regex beginners to [this link](http://www.noupe.com/php/php-regular-expressions.html) to help them get started.

**UPDATE 2**

The regex above assumes that there is always going to be a query string, so if you run up against a URI that doesn't have one, (for example, `/All-Products`), that regex won't work. To account for this, simply alter your pattern to make the query string optional:

```
$pattern = '{^/?([^\?]+)(?:\?.*)?$}'; // use an optional non-capturing group
```

-or-

```
$pattern = '{^/?([^\?]+)\??.*$}'; // make the escaped ? optional
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still leaves the leading slash for me. I've tried this code - sorry I don't know how to format it!!! $address = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$pattern = '{^/?([^\?]+)\?.*$}'; 
$replace = '$1'; 
$address = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $address); 
echo $address;

Comment: Well I must be missing something because it seems your answer produces the exact same result as my original code does. Thanks for the link to the regex page though, it should prove useful :)

Comment: Allright, since you've tried to make it work on your own, I'll help if you can let me know the output of `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Comment: The output from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is /All-Products. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ah, so if you don't specify something is optional, the whole regex fails. Thanks for pointing that out! Code works great by the way....Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$addr = preg_replace('{^/}','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);//removes leading slash
list($path) = explode('?',$addr);//removes query string
var_dump($path);
```

or

```
$path = preg_replace('{^/|\?.*}','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Explanation

- { [starting delimeter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)
- ^/ matches the first character if it is a
  slash
- | or
- \?.* matches a literal question mark followed by zero or
  more characters until the end of the string
- } [ending delimeter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

in english, "remove the first character if it is a slash or anything after a question mark including the question mark"
the `?` has special meaning so has to be escaped `\?`